# Show InfoWindow behind selected marker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm attempting to show the InfoWindow behind the selected marker.

As so:

[image]

However i'm not having any luck.

I've tried setting the zValue on both the InfoWindow and the Marker.

Any thoughts?

Regards,
Scott.

Comment: I bet that in picture, marker is that little dot, and X is part of infoWindow layout.

Comment: Can you show your layout?

Comment: @Alpha The X & Dot are the marker.  The white rectangle is the infoWindow.

Comment: @scottazord in case where "The X & Dot are the marker. The white rectangle is the infoWindow" only solution is wrapper with custom infoWindow layer and custom markers layer on top.